# поменять - на , в array php

Tags: php, массивы

у меня есть array

`Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2018-07-02) [1] => Array ( [0] => 2018-07-04 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 2018-07-04) [3] => Array ( [0] => 2018-08-22) [4] => Array ( [0] => 2018-08-23  ) [5] => Array ( [0] => 2018-08-23  ) [6] => Array ( [0] => 2018-08-27  ) )`

как поменять  -  на  ,  в array php чтоб получилось

`Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2018,07,02) [1] => Array ( [0] => 2018,07,04 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 2018,07,04) [3] => Array ( [0] => 2018,08,22) [4] => Array ( [0] => 2018,08,23  ) [5] => Array ( [0] => 2018,08,23  ) [6] => Array ( [0] => 2018,08,27  ) )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Делаете перебор массива, с помощью ***str_replace*** делаете замену подстрок в строке.

```
$result = str_replace("-", ",", "2100-01-01");
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь зделал так   foreach ($time as $item){
                $result[] = str_replace("-", ",", $item);
            }